# if var == array then

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with ids

```
$audit_answer_ids = array(85, 86);
```

now I have a foreach

```
$filtered_audits = array();
    foreach ($audits as $audit) {
      if (condition) {
        # code...
      }
      $filtered_audits[] = $audit;
    }
```

in the if (condition) I need to be able to do

```
$audit['Adusitoria']['id'] != $audit_answer_ids
```

so that way the system checks if `$audit['Adusitoria']['id']` is equal to any of the ids in the array. Will just a simple if do?

Comment: Have a look at the functions here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `in_array` function:

```
if( !in_array( $audit['Adusitoria']['id'], $audit_answer_ids )) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have `$audit['Adusitoria']['id']` variable stored.
i was thinking to loop inside the array and then comparing

**Code**

```
$audit_answer_ids = array(85, 86);

foreach ($audit_answer_ids as $data) {
    if ($audit['Adusitoria']['id'] != $data) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the best way to do it is with the in array, thanks anywais :)